# "yield" overwrites "yield from" items

Tags: php

```
<?php
function generator1(): \Traversable
{
    yield 'alpha';
    yield 'beta';
    yield 'delta';
}

function generator2(): \Traversable
{
    yield from generator1();
    yield 'upsilon';
    yield 'omega';
}

function resolve(iterable $generator) {
    foreach ($generator as $index => $item) 
        echo "$index $item" . PHP_EOL;
}

resolve(generator1());
echo  PHP_EOL;

resolve(generator2());
die;
```

Produces this result:

```
0 alpha
1 beta
2 delta

0 alpha
1 beta
2 delta
0 upsilon
1 omega
```

That last stream should be:

```
0 alpha
1 beta
2 delta
3 upsilon
4 omega
```

What's going on here? Is this a bug in PHP (I'm running v7.4.10 in Ubuntu.) How do I get the correct result without using an array or some other form of collector?

Comment: $array2 =iterator_to_array(generator2('test', '2021'), false);  ? second argument is preserve keys and defaults to true. It looks like it is overwriting the keys.

Comment: Rewrote the question to remove `iterator_to_array`. The documented functionality of `iterator_to_array` is not the problem I need to address.

Answer (score 3):

The result is a specialty of the iterator_to_array() function. The second parameter must be set to false so that all values are recorded as already noted in the comment.

This is also specifically pointed out in the [PHP manual](https://www.php.net/manual/de/language.generators.syntax.php).

```
function generator1(): \Traversable
{
    yield 'alpha';
    yield 'beta';
    yield 'delta';
    yield 'gamma';
    yield 'epsilon';
    yield 'eta';
}

function generator2(): \Traversable
{
    yield from generator1();
    yield 'upsilon';
    yield 'omega';
}

var_dump(iterator_to_array(generator2()));

var_dump(iterator_to_array(generator2(), false));
```

Result:

```
array(6) {
  [0]=>
  string(7) "upsilon"
  [1]=>
  string(5) "omega"
  [2]=>
  string(5) "delta"
  [3]=>
  string(5) "gamma"
  [4]=>
  string(7) "epsilon"
  [5]=>
  string(3) "eta"
}
array(8) {
  [0]=>
  string(5) "alpha"
  [1]=>
  string(4) "beta"
  [2]=>
  string(5) "delta"
  [3]=>
  string(5) "gamma"
  [4]=>
  string(7) "epsilon"
  [5]=>
  string(3) "eta"
  [6]=>
  string(7) "upsilon"
  [7]=>
  string(5) "omega"
}
```

[Try for yourself in the sandbox.](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/c20be30cd0f848ab9afe14ea55584e37dfa5f751)

This becomes clear when keys and values are output with foreach.

```
foreach(generator2() as $key => $value){
  var_dump($key,$value);
}
```

Output:

```
int(0) string(5) "alpha"
int(1) string(4) "beta"
int(2) string(5) "delta"
int(3) string(5) "gamma"
int(4) string(7) "epsilon"
int(5) string(3) "eta"
int(0) string(7) "upsilon"
int(1) string(5) "omega"
```